# formulas on the left

Tags: equations, split

I would like to change the way the formulas are written in my thesis. As it can be seen, I have both `equation` and `eqnarray`. Sometimes, the option `\\` is used to start a new line. If this option is used for the `equation`, then the option `begin{split}` is added.

```
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
x_{nmk}\in\{0,1\}, f_{kn},u_{kn},r_{ink},y_{in},t_{k}\geq 0, \\ \ i=1,...,N, k=1,...,K,n=1,...,N, \label{nnb8}
\end{split}
\end{equation}
\begin{eqnarray}
f_{kn}\geq f_{km}-\sum_{i=1}^N r_{inkl}-(1-x_{mnk})M, \nonumber \\ \ k=1,...,K,m=0,...,N,n=1,...,N\label{loadbalance8}\\
f_{k0}= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N r_{ink},\ k=1,...,K\label{loadbalance9}
\end{eqnarray}
```

I would like to change the way the first line of the formula is displayed when there are more than one line. In that case, the first line of the equation and only the first line of the equation should move to the left. The second line should start as it is suposed from the right.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! You shouldn't use `eqnarray`, which has been deprecated for more than 20 years and can lead to bad spacing. You should replace it with `align` from `amsmath`.

Comment: @Francesco Zangaro, any news?

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\label{nnb8}
x_{nmk}\in\{0,1\},
    \quad   & f_{kn},u_{kn},r_{ink},y_{in},t_{k}\geq 0, \\ 
            & \ i=1,...,N, k=1,...,K,n=1,...,N, 
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
f_{kn}\geq f_{km}-
    & \sum_{i=1}^N r_{\mathit{inkl}}-(1-x_{mnk})M,   \nonumber \\ 
    & k=1,\dotsc,K,m=0,\dotsc,N,n=1,\dotsc,N
                                            \label{loadbalance8}\\
    & f_{k0}= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N r_{ink},\ k=1,\dotsc,K
                                            \label{loadbalance9}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

In your MWE is not clear where you have separate variables or text in subscripts. Maybe is my correction of `inkl` wrong (if this is set of four variables). Also I discourage you to use `eqnarray`, instead it is better `align` from `amsmath` or `mathtools` package.

**Addendum:**
It seem that probably desired form of equations is:

[image]

In eq. 2 is used `multlined` environment defined in `mathtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
\begin{split}\label{nnb8}
x_{nmk}\in\{0,1\},
    \quad   & f_{kn},u_{kn},r_{ink},y_{in},t_{k}\geq 0, \\
            & \ i=1,...,N, k=1,...,K,n=1,...,N,
\end{split}
\end{equation}

\begin{align}
f_{kn}
    & \begin{multlined}[t][0.6\hsize]
        \geq f_{km} - \sum_{i=1}^N r_{\mathit{inkl}}-(1-x_{mnk})M,   \\
        k=1,\dotsc,K,m=0,\dotsc,N,n=1,\dotsc,N
        \end{multlined}                     \label{loadbalance8}\\
f_{k0} & = \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N r_{ink},\ k=1,\dotsc,K
                                            \label{loadbalance9}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2):

For single equations split opver more than one line you can use `multline` which gives the staggered layout automatically. Otherewise use `align` not `eqnarray`, also `\dots` not `...`

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
aaaa
\begin{multline}
x_{nmk}\in\{0,1\}, f_{kn},u_{kn},r_{ink},y_{in},t_{k}\geq 0, \\
 i=1,\dots,N, k=1,\dots,K,n=1,\dots,N, \label{nnb8}
\end{multline}

bbb
\begin{align}
f_{kn}&\geq f_{km}-\sum_{i=1}^N r_{inkl}-(1-x_{mnk})M, \nonumber \\ 
&\qquad k=1,\dots,K,m=0,\dots,N,n=1,\dots,N\label{loadbalance8}\\
f_{k0}&= \sum_{i=1}^N \sum_{n=1}^N r_{ink}, k=1,\dots,K\label{loadbalance9}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

I just used your first few set of equations, and tried to attain what you want,

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{align}
    x_{nmk}\in\{0,1\}, f_{kn},u_{kn},r_{ink},y_{in},t_{k}\geq 0,& \\ \ 
    &i=1,...,N, k=1,...,K,n=1,...,N, 
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

using this will give you
[image]

as you asked with one and only the first line of equation on the left, and the rest of the lines starting from right. This you can achieve with the `\align` equation environment that is available in `amsmath` package. By following this notion you can set the rest of your equations at your will.